# Active background color switch in jQuery 1.6.4

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This jQuery code changes the background color in all jQuery versions except for version 1.6.4. Why is version 1.6.4 not properly running this code?

HTML:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="bin" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr> <a href="#"><th style="text-align:left; padding-top: 20px;" width="10%" id="row-1">Symbol <img src="/images/sort-arrow-up.png" title="Sort by Symbol" alt="Sort by Symbol" class="sort-right move-left bottom-image" id="image1"/></th></a>

            <th style="text-align:left;" width="20%" id="row-2">Company
                <br><span class="move_right">Name</span> 
                <img src="/images/sort-arrow-up.png" title="Sort by Company Name" alt="Sort by Company Name" class="sort-right move-left" id="image2" />
            </th>
            <th style="text-align:center;" width="12%" id="row-3"><span class="center-text">Buy</span>
                <br>Date
                <img title="Sort by Buy Date" src="/images/sort-arrow.png" alt="Sort by Buy Date" id="image3" />
            </th>
            <th style="text-align:center;" width="10%" id="row-4"><span class="center-text">Buy</span>
                <br>Price &nbsp;
                <img title="Sort by Buy Price" src="/images/sort-arrow.png" alt="Sort by Buy Price" id="image4" />
            </th>
            <th style="text-align:center;" width="9%" id="row-5"><span class="center-text">Closed</span>
                <br>Price &nbsp;
                <img title="Sort by Closed Price" src="/images/sort-arrow.png" alt="Sort by Closed Price" id="image5" />
            </th>
            <th style="text-align:center;" width="9%" id="row-6"><span class="center-text">Closed</span>
                <br>Date &nbsp;
                <img title="Sort by Closed Date" src="/images/sort-arrow.png" alt="Sort by Closed Date" id="image6" />
            </th>
            <th style="text-align:center;" width="10%" id="row-7"><span class="center-text">Total</span>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $('#bin').on('click', 'th', function(){
        $(this).parent().children().removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
tr th.active
{
  background-color: #7DAFFF;!important
}
```

**DEMO** - [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zE4Rb/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess jQuery 1.6.4 did not recognize .on

Here's defference between library 1.6.4 and later

http://jsperf.com/on-vs-delegate-jquery/3

.delegate should work in 1.6.4 
later they change it for .on

Here it is with click(function()

```
    $(function(){
       $('#bin th').click(function(){
          $(this).parent().children().removeClass('active');
          $(this).addClass('active');
       });
    });
```

[**EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/SzymonDziewonski/zE4Rb/3/)

Comment: You are right, it's only supported in 1.7+. Says so right here in the docs http://api.jquery.com/on#on1.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it like this ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zE4Rb/6/)) and it works fine:

JS:

```
$(function(){
    $('#bin th').click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
tr th.active
{
  background-color: #7DAFFF;
}
```

Turns out it was the .on method that was causing the problem.

Comment: You tested that in version 1.9.1, not 1.6.4 @Baszz

Answer (score 0):

`on` is not supported in jquery `1.6.4` you can use `delegate('th','click')`